# Link CTA to another page - Can it say "[Action] now"?

Tags: user-expectation, hyperlinks, copywriting, cta

I've seen in a couple places both web and mobile where a hyperlinked phrase serves as a CTA. Its form is something like, "Redeem now for..." or "Enroll now.." Clicking or tapping the link leads to a page where the action takes place, but tapping the link itself doesn't make the action happen.

Is there a recommendation against making the copy for the link an action that actually doesn't take place (until a next screen)? Is it different between web and mobile? Or is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the button initiates a clear path of action, that seems fine.  Active language drives, well, action, and the button is your first step in the journey.  You wouldn't want to, say, click an "Enroll Now" button and land on an "About Us" page that had contact information at the bottom.  That would be a UX DISASTER!